# PHP - MySQL DB Select from Joined table, display column with duplicate name?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to use PHP to display a table on a page.
My select statement consists of a join of two tables and each table contains the columns called "`id`", where one table's "`id`" column is joined via the other table's "`project_id`" column.

i.e.
Table A
`A.id`, `A.description`

Table B
`B.id`, `B.project_id`

`WHERE
A.id = B.project_id`

My problem is that when I try to display both the "`project_id`" column and the "`B.id`" column (without aliasing the columns) it just automatically grabs the "`A.id`" column.
I have aliased the table names, but not the column names, and I have tried using "B.id" instead of just "id" in the PHP code.

How do I grab the right data column?? I would like to know if there is another solution besides aliasing the columns, or if that is the proper way to deal with this situation.

Thank you

Comment: Then why don't you alias?

Comment: id like to know if there is a solution without aliasing or if the actual workaround for this is to alias

Comment: That is no workaround. If you have multiple columns with the same name you must alias. Or do you expect the compiler to guess right? Limit your query to the columns you really need and you don't have a problem. Avoid `select *`

Comment: `select tableA.id AS a_id, tableB.id AS b_id ...` would do the trick.

Comment: Why can't PHP read "B.id" when I try to call that column? I would have been fine with just calling it directly by Tablename.Columnname instead of aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you probably don't need to use an alias as you can simply not select `A.id`. You already have that available in `B.project_id` so if you really don't want to use an alias (I don't see why...), just don't include it in your `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It would always assume `id` is the attribute you are joining the tables on by default. You will definitely need to provide `alias`. It is not only just syntax, but also makes it much easier for people to read and identify which `id` you're taking about.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give it an alias

```
Select a.id, b.id AS bID
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.id = bID
```

Gave column alias also, perhaps if OP had posted some actual code it would have been clearer that he wanted column alias, not table alias

Comment: Which you don't in your example :)

Comment: i think its quite clear (to a knowledgeable person in this area) from context that I needed column alias. IMHO. and trying to "blame" the OP is quite the save face tactic, i might have chosen your *fixed* response as an answer in a different circumstance.

Comment: No worries mate. Hope you got the answer that you were looking for, whomever it was that helped you. To be honest I probably spent about 3 seconds reading your question, I'm sure everyone on this site who works in IT is in the same boat of being very busy everyday, but offering whatever time they can to helping people. It's just my personal preference that code is posted in the question, it's quicker to read than paragraphs of text. Good luck with your work.